# possible values for android:inputMethod="" in xml for EditText

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext, xml-attribute

I know that android:inputMethod="" is deprecated but still can any one give me the example values. Specially When we have our own keyboard with own inputmethod. I tried with many ways but each time it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

I have one Example for that

```
  android:inputMethod="android.text.method.DateTimeInputMethod"
```

specifies that this TextView should use the specified input 
method (specified by fully-qualified class name).

Comment: thanks but can you give me the example of custom inputMethod type